# How java security doPrivileged method is blocking arbitrary scripts

Tags: javascript, java, security, nashorn

I have implemented a class as shown below,

```
class Example4 {
  private static class RestrictedAccessControlContext {
    private static final AccessControlContext INSTANCE;

    static {
      INSTANCE = new AccessControlContext(
                   new ProtectionDomain[] {
                     new ProtectionDomain(null, null) // No permissions
                   });
    }
  }

  private static void evalScript(final String input)
      throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
   ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    // Restrict permission using the two-argument form of doPrivileged()
    try {
      AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {

          public Object run() throws Exception {
            engine.eval(new FileReader(new File(input)));
            return null;
          }
        },
        // From nested class
        RestrictedAccessControlContext.INSTANCE);

    } catch (PrivilegedActionException pae) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
```

and I'm passing below script as an argument to the main method which can create multiple files inside the system.

```
var fImport = new JavaImporter(java.io.File); 

i=0;
while(true)
{
     with(fImport) { var f = new File('new'+i); 
     f.createNewFile(); 
     i++;
}
}
```

So allowing such classes in the system is obviously a bad practice but in cert it has been suggested as a best practise to use a class like this
([Click here to see the examples](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/IDS52-J.+Prevent+code+injection)). So how this doPrivileged method is providing protection to the system against executing arbitrary scripts ?
and what are the changes I need to make in my code to prevent this file creation(Best Practise)

Answer (score 0):

If you call scriptEngine.eval(String) or scriptEngine.eval(FileReader), your script is already treated as "sandbox" code. You don't need to do anything special.

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
      ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
      try {
          e.eval("java.lang.System.exit(0)");
      } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println(ex); }

      try {
          e.eval("new java.io.File('.').list()");
      } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println(ex); }
   }
}

$ javac Main.java

$ java -Djava.security.manager Main
```

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.0")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "." "read")

The above happens even if you give "AllPermission" to Main class!

If you do want to grant permissions [other than sandbox permissions] to scripts, you need to use 'load' or 'loadWithNewGlobal' or URLReader.

Please refer to https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+script+security+permissions

Minor note on the code you've above: you're creating FileReader within a doPrivileged block which runs in no-permissions acc. context. If you run your code with security manager on, it'd have failed even before reaching script engine's eval.

Comment: In the same case (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+script+security+permissions) if someone try to execute this with the command Java Main,  he will be able to do it isn't it ? since security policy is not defined inside the  class. So how to prevent it ?
How to define only permitted files can be given as input

Comment: I don't get you. There is nothing to prevent! Script from unknown origin is evaluated as sandbox code by default and so it'll get access controlled exception as shown above.  There is no injection attack possible here.

Comment: If you don't turn on security manager [you mentioned java Main], then you are asking for trouble anyway! or you trust the java code that you run - such a trusted code should not remove your arbitrary files, right? Same way, it should not evaluate arbitrary script.

Comment: I'm bit confused with this, I have run the code using
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=./test.policy Example4 test.js and it throws a permission denied exception for the script but and when I run it as Java Example4 test.js, using the above script I'm able to create files inside the folder.
So if an attacker trying to destroy the system by creating multiple files inside ,he can simply execute the normal command isn't it ?since no security is enforced in the Example4.java class.

Comment: So how I should change my java code which can check whether the script that is trying to execute is added to the policy file or not ?

Comment: when you run "java Example4 test.js", you're running the JVM without the security manager. With that mode, you've to run only trusted code anyway! If you run something without security manager on, all bets are off!  if attacker can run arbitrary process (in this case "java process" on your machine, then you're already compromised - not just java, he can run anything, right?

Comment: All script security or any security of Java code is meaningful only when you run java with security manager turned on. With that mode, arbitrary script code does not pose any danger.

Comment: @sundatatajan Running `java.lang.System.exit(0)` in a script within a Java class on Wildfly 14 effectively exits the system and there are no exceptions thrown, even though Wildfly out of the box is configured with Security Manager ON. What is the configuration in the Security Manager that needs to be looked to disable instantiating ANY Java classes within the script?